# How to create a async function and export it?

Tags: node.js, express

Using node + express. I want to create a module that use several querys.

**how can I export this asynchronous function to app.js?**

This is the function that im trying to make it work:

**app.js (where io are socketio instance)**

```
const users = require('./sockets/users')(io)
```

**users.js**

```
const Users = require('../models/Users.model')
const users = async function(client){
        client.on('connection', socket =>{
                socket.on('userAdd',(data) =>{
                    console.log(data);
                })
                const users = await Users.find()
                console.log(users[0]);
        })        
}
module.exports = users
```

**Error: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function**

Comment: Same way as you export ordinary functions.

Comment: yes because your await statement is out of your async function. check it

Comment: yes, but i need to create that query inside of userAdd event @JuhilSomaiya how can i do it?

Comment: my bad, i just saw it

Answer (score 0):

First create two files. you can create functions into one and can export it and in another file you can import that functions. check the code below.

```
> server.js

const addition = require('./addition.js') // path to your another file

const result = addition.add(5, 8) // calling function of another file
console.log(result)
```

another file

```
> addition.js

const add = (x, y) => x + y;

module.exports = { add } // export this function
```

output:

```
13
```

Comment: excuse me for the delay,i added context

Answer (score 0):

I was typing the async keyword in the incorrect function. **Its in the connection function**

```
const Users = require('../models/Users.model')
const users = function(client){
        client.on('connection', async socket =>{
                socket.on('userAdd',(data) =>{
                    console.log(data);
                })
                const users = await Users.find()
                console.log(users[0]); //user 1
        })        
}
module.exports = users
```

Comment: Is this right answer for you? Or you just edit your question?

Comment: no, is the right answer, now  i can get the data in const users = await Users.find()

Answer (score -2):

You can try to use a class for that and export that class and use it

Comment: what's the need of class here ?

Comment: Ummm... Why you need to create class if you can just export functions?